# postgresql Select max value if other field is null

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, aggregate-functions

I have to perform a select

```
select  field1, field2
from *table
where field1 not null and ( field2 in (4,5,6) or max(field2))
```

so if field2  = 4 or 5 or 6 and field1 is not null then ok
else if field1 is null then to be taken maxim value of field2 where field1 is not null [max(field2)] ..

Comment: What's the mean about `field1 is not null [max(field2)] `?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select  field1, field2
from * table
where case when field1 is not null then field2 in (4,5,6) else field2 in 
(select max(field2) field2 from table) end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select field1, field2
from (select t.*, max(field2) over () as max_field2
      from *table
     ) t
where field1 not null and (field2 in (4, 5, 6, max_field2));
```

A subquery/cross join can also be used:

```
select field1, field2
from *table t
where field1 is not null and
      (field2 in (4, 5, 6) or
       field2 = (select max(t2.field2) from *table2)
      );
```